# Filter Groupby if contains specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Say I have the following dataframe covering hundreds of different names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"NAME":["A", "A", "A" ,"A", 
                       "B", "B", "B", 
                       "C", "C", "C", "C",
                       "D", "D",],
               "CLASS":["LI","BO","EQ","AI",
                           "LI", "EQ", "AI", 
                           "LI","BO","EQ","AI",
                           "EQ", "AI", 
                          ]})
```

Using the groupby-function of Pandas, how am I supposed to filter out only those names that contain both EQ AND AI but NOT BO? Ideally, I should obtain the following:

```
NAME CLASS
B    LI
B    EQ
B    AI
D    EQ
D    AI
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with set operations:

```
out = df[df.groupby('NAME')['CLASS']
           .transform(lambda x: ((S:=set(x))>={'EQ', 'AI'}) and ('BO' not in S))]
# or
# out = df[df.groupby('NAME')['CLASS']
#            .transform(lambda x: ((S:=set(x))>={'EQ', 'AI'})
#                       and not S.intersection({'BO'}))]
```

Variant with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
g = df.groupby('NAME')['CLASS'].agg(set)
out = df[df['NAME'].isin(g.index[(g >= {'EQ', 'AI'}) & ~(g >= {'BO'})])]
```

Output:

```
   NAME CLASS
4     B    LI
5     B    EQ
6     B    AI
11    D    EQ
12    D    AI
```

###### Intermediates

with an extra group for completeness

```
# transform approach
   NAME CLASS  g >= {'EQ', 'AI'}  ~(g >= {'BO'})      &
0     A    LI               True           False  False
1     A    BO               True           False  False
2     A    EQ               True           False  False
3     A    AI               True           False  False
4     B    LI               True            True   True
5     B    EQ               True            True   True
6     B    AI               True            True   True
7     C    LI               True           False  False
8     C    BO               True           False  False
9     C    EQ               True           False  False
10    C    AI               True           False  False
11    D    EQ               True            True   True
12    D    AI               True            True   True
13    E    AI              False            True  False

# agg approach
                     g  (g >= {'EQ', 'AI'})  ~(g >= {'BO'})      &
NAME                                                              
A     {LI, EQ, BO, AI}                 True           False  False
B         {LI, EQ, AI}                 True            True   True
C     {LI, EQ, BO, AI}                 True           False  False
D             {EQ, AI}                 True            True   True
E                 {AI}                False            True  False
```